# expo-cli@6.0.6: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12 <=16". Got "18.10.0"

Tags: node.js, react-native, version-control, expo, dependencies

I was running my code about 9 hours ago with no problem. Now, `npx react-native run-ios` does not work. I figured maybe I needed to run `yarn` to fix some dependencies, and running yarn got 2/4's through the process before returning the following error...

```
expo-cli@6.0.6: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12 <=16". Got "18.10.0"
```

Now I understand what this is telling me, that the `expo-cli` dependency needs a node version between 12.0.0 and 16.0.0, but I'm slightly taken aback by this, the only way that makes sense to me is if the `expo-cli` literally updated yesterday night.

I added the following to my `package.json` in hopes to mitigate the error to no avail...

```
  "engines" : { 
    "node" : "<=16.0.0" 
  },
```

Do I need to downgrade / upgrade the expo-cli? I'm using bare RN but with expo modules appended to it

Answer (score 0):

Weird issue, I restarted my machine and the error disappeared entirely. Hopefully this doesn't happen again or if it does, its as easily fixable